# how to style the QScrollBar when the content is not scrolling?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I want to style the scrollbars. I am able to apply styles to scrollbar when scrollarea content is scrolling. 
But when the content is not scrolling the style is not getting applied to it.

I have used below style elements:

```
QScrollBar:vertical{ /** some styles **/ };
QScrollBar::handle:vertical{ /** some styles **/ };
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical{ /** some styles **/ };
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical{ /** some styles **/ };
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical{ /** some styles **/ };
QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical{ /** some styles **/ };
```

These elements works fine when content is scrolling.

I tried to use below element when content is not scrolling:

```
QScrollBar:vertical:disabled{ /** some styles **/ };
```

But doesn't have any effect :(

Anyone has this similar issue please reply..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QScrollBar::handle:disabled{ /** some styles **/  }
```